# Dynamodb authenticate user in swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Without authenticate method I successfully get all tables data from dynamodb.

Somewhat I am new to AWS. My main query is only register user with associate user in that pool only access data. I have only user pool id.

So how its possible to authenticate that user and get tables from dynamodb.

I am not getting what i need to do in my code.

My requirement is only register used login and getting that data.

So can any one explain the process how to do in swift ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html

Comment: @RanHassid I want to get that data in my app permission already set. In my app how to authenticate ?

Comment: I would definitely recommend that you try AWS Mobile Hub: https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/
It lets you create dynamo tables in a easy way setting permissions for them and also helps you demo the operations with / without users being signed in to the app. It also has working demos for sign in with Google and Facebook.